# Google analytics page per session is more than 1 for SPA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, create-react-app, gtag.js

I have built a SPA using Create React App. I have integrated google analytics and using google tag manager(tag) for sending events.

```
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx');
```

While analyzing the events I have noticed that [my application](https://covid19quarantine.in/home?source=GJSO) is only firing landing pageview event(Only on first-page user visit).

What I am not able to figure out is even though the application has fired pageview event only once how page/session > 1. Can someone please help me understand this mystery and how does Goggle analytics calculate page per session?

[image: Image from GA dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en.

For example, if a time based expiration is considered for a session, if someone opens a page, and let's say, reloads it for some reason, his session will now comprise of 2 page views, not 1.

The existence of such instances could be the reason why your SPA has 1.28 pages / session.

Comment: The link you shared is really insightful.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pages Per Session

- *Quick Description* = Average number of pages viewed per session
- *Calculation*: PageViews / Sessions
- *Referred to as* = Pages Per Session

This shows you how many pages the average person views on your website per session… What we mean by `sessions` is essentially **all of the actions performed during a person visiting your site**.

A person may visit your site three times, the person is defined as a `user` and each visit (in its entirety) is called a `session`.

**Sessions ::**
A session is a collection of activities that all took place on your website within a time frame for a single user.

**Pageviews ::**
PageViews represent the number of times pages on your site have been visited/viewed.

If a user comes to your site and views 3 pages before leaving, this will increase total PageViews by 3.

#### Calculating Pages Per Session

This is a good engagement metric for businesses that want low bounce rates and high levels of engagement. A number, typically measured to a single decimal place, represents this metric.

For example, a website that has had 1,000 sessions and 3,500 PageViews, we would get the following:

> **3,500** / **1,000** = **3.5** Pages Per Session (PageViews Per Session)

---

#### Pages/Session Behavior for Single Page Application(SPA)

As per GA, Repeated views of a single page are counted which might be happening in your application.

You can find the data for pages per session by navigating to `“Audience” > “Overview.”`

Pageviews aren’t necessarily unique, as the same user can view the same page 5 times and log 5 pageviews. However, it’s still a good indicator of the overall engagement. Just be sure to place any analysis within the context of how the metric is defined.